# IBM Worklight 5.0.5:Control Worklight Push notification Subscribe/Unsubscribe through OS's notification handle

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to invoke the `WL.Client.Push.subscribe(alias, options)` or `WL.Client.Push.unsubscribe (alias, options)` through the `Show notifications` in Android and `Include` in iOS. Instead of adding a Subscribe/Unsubscribe handle in my app,i want it to be handled through the OS's controls.

[image: Android Notification control]

[image: iOSNotification control]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those things are not the same.

Subscribing/unsubscribing to push notifications is one thing. Controlling how the notifications are displayed/displayed at all in the device is another.

The answer is then, IMO: No, you can't use those features to control whether your application (device, rather) is subscribed or unsubscribed from push notifications.

By subscribing/unsubscribing, you manage the server state regarding the notifications.

That said, in your application you should be able to query for the state of these controls for the app (in iOS that should be UIApplication > enabledRemoteNotificationTypes), and based on the result to subscribe or unsubscribe. To do that, you'll need to write a Cordova plug-in. I don't know how well that was supported back in Worklight 5.0.5.x, that is a pretty old version of Worklight.

You should tell your customer to upgrade. :-)